# Vuejs - Reference to HTMLElement becomes stale after using it in slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to use Vue on an existing page where there are some controls outside of my control. I wanted to wrap the controls with a Vue component, but all references to those controls are stale after Vue is initialized.

See the following codesandbox for repro: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-fast-405up

The component wrapping the controls is super simply:

Component:

```html
  <div id="app">
    <slot />
  </div>
```

Page:

```html
    <div id="app">
      <test-container>
        <div id="some-element">Initial Text</div>
      </test-container>
    </div>
```

```js
var element = document.getElementById("some-element");

new Vue({
  components: {
    TestContainer: App
  }
}).$mount("#app");

console.log(element);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("updating element...");
  element.innerText = "Updated Text";
  console.log(element.innerText);
  console.log(document.getElementById("some-element").innerText);
}, 1000);
```

This will print:

```
updating element... 
Updated Text 
Initial Text // should be Updated Text
```

Is there a way to not break existing references to those controls when rendered in a slot? I want to keep rendering the existing controls, but wrap them with a Stepper component for example.

Comment: I don't think Vue offers a workaround for this out of the box, but this person seems to have faced a similar issue and has a possible solution (I can't vouch for whether it works or not): https://gist.github.com/loilo/a3ec6dbb78d42594b45ec7ebd00139c7

Comment: Although it adds quite some overhead to the form I'm building, it works. Thanks for finding this!

Comment: No problem. It's an interesting issue I haven't come across before.